# What does the timeout in nerve signify?

Tags: configuration, timeout, service-discovery

I'm trying to discover few services using **nerve**.

While I came across the **timeout configuration** specified in nerve [docs](https://github.com/airbnb/nerve).

```
timeout: (optional) maximum time the check can take; defaults to 100ms
```

However when I look at the [examples](https://github.com/airbnb/nerve/blob/4c1c6598b063b2077d44de055d97f2e28adc90a7/example/nerve.conf.json) provided, the timeout is mentioned as "0.2".

Does this mean the timeout for these examples are "**0.2ms**"? Is that even a valid configuration for timeout?
Or is 0.2 considered as **2 sec**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the code for nerve and looks like the timeout configuration provided in nerve json would just be read this value and directly pass it to [http client](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Net/HTTP.html) as read_timeout without any additional processing.

As per Ruby documentation, this value is in seconds. 
**So 0.2 means 200ms.**

I'm assuming [Nerve Docs](https://github.com/airbnb/nerve/) was not updated or has a mistake w.r.t documentation.

> read_timeout[R]
>   Number of seconds to wait for one block to be read
>   (via one read(2) call). Any number may be used, including Floats for
>   fractional seconds. If the HTTP object cannot read data in this many
>   seconds, it raises a Net::ReadTimeout exception. The default value is
>   60 seconds.